# Why boost::replace_all_copy is not working? C++

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to make working code to replace text of line. Using boost_1_64_0 .

```
getline (ifs, line);
cout << line << endl;

// 1.
boost::replace_all(line, "abc", "hij");
boost::replace_all(line, "def", "klm");

// 2.
line = boost::replace_all_copy
boost::replace_all_copy<string>
(
 ("abc def abc def", "abc", "hij")
 ,  "def"
 ,  "klm"
);
```

I am getting these errors:

```
main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
main.cpp|37|error: no match for 'operator=' in 'line = boost::algorithm::replace_all_copy'|
main.cpp|37|note: candidates are:|
\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|543|note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]|
mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|543|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'const std::basic_string<char>&'|
mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|551|note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]|
mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|551|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'const char*'|
mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|562|note: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]|
mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|562|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'char'|
main.cpp|38|error: expected ';' before 'boost'|
main.cpp|53|error: expected '}' before 'else'|
```

Why the error happens or how can I correct them?

Answer (score 5):

You have written obviously broken code:

```
line = boost::replace_all_copy boost::replace_all_copy<string>(...)
```

Comment: Thank you so it should be like this... `             line = boost::replace_all_copy (
             boost::replace_all_copy<string>
                  ("abc def abc def", "abc", "hij")
                  ,  "def"
                  ,  "klm"
                );`